# Extract data from sql string

Tags: t-sql

I have the following data in a column. I want to extract the 'matching details' score just showing as 542. The problem is the matching score can also be more than 3 characters long. Can someone help?

```
 MatchingDetails score="542" maxScore="-96" matchRule="abcdef"><rule name="Person_Forename" score="279" /><rule name="Person_Surname" score="263"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a combination of `charindex`, `patindex`, and `substring`:

```
DECLARE @S varchar(100) = 'MatchingDetails score="542" maxScore="-96" matchRule="abcdef">'


SELECT SUBSTRING(@S, 
                 patindex('% score="%', @S) + 8,
                 charindex('"', @S, patindex('% score="%', @S) + 9) - patindex('% score="%', @S) - 8)
```

Result:

```
542
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's so helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If your data is an XML string, perhaps something like this

**Example (corrected xml)**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '
<MatchingDetails score="542" maxScore="-96" matchRule="abcdef" >
    <rule name="Person_Forename" score="279"></rule>
    <rule name="Person_Surname" score="263"></rule>
</MatchingDetails>
'

Select convert(xml,@S).value('MatchingDetails[1]/@score','int')
```

**Returns**

```
542
```